# Optional parameter in cucumber

Tags: cucumber

I have a step definition in which I'd like to have an optional parameter. I believe an example of two calls to this step explains better than anything else what I'm after.

```
I check the favorite color count
I check the favorite color count for email address 'john@anywhere.example'
```

In the first instance, I would like to use a default email address.

What's a good way of defining this step? I'm no regexp guru. I tried doing this but cucumber gave me an error regarding regexp argument mismatches:

```
Then(/^I check the favorite color count (for email address "([^"]*))*"$/) do  |email = "default_email@somewhere.example"|
```

Comment: What's wrong with two step definitions?

Comment: Nothing inherently.  Just want to stretch my cucumber muscles and see what's possible.

Comment: Two definitions means most of time duplicate code, so theoretically conditional clause is better.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`optional.feature`:

```
Feature: Optional parameter

  Scenario: Use optional parameter
    When I check the favorite color count
    When I check the favorite color count for email address 'john@anywhere.example'
```

`optional_steps.rb`

```
When /^I check the favorite color count(?: for email address (.*))?$/ do |email|
  email ||= "default@domain.example"
  puts 'using ' + email
end
```

output

```
Feature: Optional parameter

  Scenario: Use optional parameter
    When I check the favorite color count
      using default@domain.example
    When I check the favorite color count for email address 'john@anywhere.example'
      using 'john@anywhere.example'

1 scenario (1 passed)
2 steps (2 passed)
0m0.047s
```

Comment: That works great, and thanks for it, but may I ask what the `?:` bit does?

Comment: `?:` is a [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html).

Answer (score 0):

@larryq, you were closer to the solution than you thought...

`optional.feature`:

```
Feature: optional parameter

Scenario: Parameter is not given
    Given xyz
    When I check the favorite color count
    Then foo

Scenario: Parameter is given
    Given xyz
    When I check the favorite color count for email address 'john@example.com'
    Then foo
```

`optional_steps.rb`

```
When /^I check the favorite color count( for email address \'(.*)\'|)$/ do |_, email|
    puts "using '#{email}'"
end

Given /^xyz$/ do
end

Then /^foo$/ do
end
```

output:

```
Feature: optional parameter

Scenario: Parameter is not given
    Given xyz
    When I check the favorite color count
        using ''
    Then foo

Scenario: Parameter is given
    Given xyz
    When I check the favorite color count for email address 'john@example.com'
        using 'john@example.com'
    Then foo

2 scenarios (2 passed)
6 steps (6 passed)
0m9.733s
```