# Cucumber\Java: Defining a step with both optional words and parameter

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-java

Although similar to [Optional parameter in cucumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346348/optional-parameter-in-cucumber), still it is for ruby programmers which I am not familiar with...

So what I'd like to have is to be able to use either one of those two options:

```
Given REST ADCC Login with username "admin" and password "admin"
```

and

```
Given REST ADCC Login with username "admin"
```

For the latter I would allow myself to set the password with the username value for testing purposes only.

The step implementation as I understood is:

```
@Given("^REST ADCC Login with username \"(.*)\"(?: and password \"(.*)\")?( negative)?$")
public void login(String username, String password, String negative) {
        loginLogoutStepsHandler.login(username, password);
}
```

but then, when I use the first step option, with the password defined, the password param gets null as it should have been "admin".

What is wrong with my syntax?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Create two step definitions. Call one from the other:

```java
@Given("REST ADCC Login with username \"(.*)\" and password \"(.*)\"")
public void restADCCLoginWithUsernameAndPassword(String username, String password) {
    // log in...
}

@Given("REST ADCC Login with username \"(.*)\"\"")
public void restADCCLoginWithUsernameAndPassword(String username) {
    restADCCLoginWithUsernameAndPassword(username, "test");
}
```

It achieves code reuse without getting clever with regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks! It didn't work for me. However, I managed to find the solution, also following your idea to abandon the single step solution :) As you can see, the changes between your solution and the one which worked are minor. Thanks again!

Comment: To be clear, the `.*` regex construct is greedy by default so the second regexp matches  everything between the first and last quotes

Comment: Oh, geez. I didn't realize the two steps were so similar. The `.*` syntax would have caused both steps to be a match for the `with password` variant.

Answer (score 0):

for whoever may be of interest for them, what eventually worked (following the idea of Greg of using two separate implementations) for me was:

```
@Given("^REST ADCC Login with username \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void rest_ADCC_Login_with_username(String username) throws Throwable {
    loginLogoutStepsHandler.login(username, username);
}

@Given("^REST ADCC Login with username \"([^\"]*)\" and password \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void rest_ADCC_Login_with_username_and_password(String username, String password) throws Throwable {
    loginLogoutStepsHandler.login(username, password);
}
```